# JavaScript transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
//obiekt TopBottomBar 

function TopBottomBar(obj) {
  //properties
  this.position = obj.position;
  this.message = obj.message;
  this.link = obj.link;
  this.baseDiv = this.createNewBar();
 
}

 //methods
TopBottomBar.prototype.show = function(){
    
  var allNodes = document.body.childNodes;
  console.log(!document.getElementById('topBottomBar'));
  if(this.position === 'top' && !document.getElementById('topBottomBar'))
  {
    document.body.insertBefore(this.baseDiv, allNodes[0]);
    this.baseDiv.className = ' top-animation';
    document.getElementById('closelink').addEventListener('click', this.hide.bind(this));

  }else if(this.position === 'bottom' && !document.getElementById('topBottomBar'))
  {
    document.body.insertBefore(this.baseDiv, allNodes[allNodes.length - 1].nextSibling);
    this.baseDiv.className = 'bottom-animation';
    document.getElementById('closelink').addEventListener('click', this.hide.bind(this));

  }else{
    console.log('Ziomus bar istnieje, tymczasowa wiadomość');
    return;
  }
}


TopBottomBar.prototype.createNewBar = function(){

  var baseDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var button = document.createElement("a");
  button.href = this.link;
  var icon = document.createElement("i");
  icon.className += 'fa fa-btc';
  button.id += 'buttonlink';
  var textButton = document.createTextNode(this.message);
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  var closeButton = document.createTextNode("X");
  span.id += 'closelink';

//dodanie w kolejnosci, ikona, przycisk, X zamkniecia
  span.appendChild(closeButton);
  button.appendChild(textButton);
  baseDiv.appendChild(icon);
  baseDiv.appendChild(button);
  baseDiv.appendChild(span);
  baseDiv.id += 'topBottomBar';

  if(this.position === 'top'){
    baseDiv.className += 'top-fixed';
  }
  if(this.position ===  'bottom'){
    baseDiv.className += 'bottom-fixed';
  }

  return baseDiv;
}


TopBottomBar.prototype.hide = function(){
    var elementToDelete = document.getElementById('topBottomBar');
    document.body.removeChild(elementToDelete);
}



var topBarparameters = {
  message: "Get Widget",
  position: "top",
  link: '#'
}


var bottomBarparameters = {
  message: "Get Widget",
  position: "bottom",
  link: '#'
}




var upBar = new TopBottomBar(topBarparameters);
var bottomBar = new TopBottomBar(bottomBarparameters);

document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('click', upBar.show.bind(upBar));
document.getElementById('down').addEventListener('click', bottomBar.show.bind(bottomBar));
```

```css
body
{
 background-image: url('background.png');
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: Open Sans,sans-serif;
 position: relative;
}

#nav
{
 position: relative;
 font-size: 25px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1.5em;
 background-color: #C21B1B;
 padding-top: 10px;
 text-align: center;

}

#nav a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: black;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 20px;
 display: block;
 background-color: #4123C0;
 width: 8em;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#nav a:hover
{
 background-color: #2001A0;
 color: white;

}


#container
{
 width: 75%;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#footer
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 3em;
 background-color: #372323;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 padding-top: 10px;
}



#topBottomBar 
{
    color: #f4f4f4!important;
    background: #363d4d!important;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap!important;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 42px!important;
    text-align: center!important;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 0;
    z-index: 30000;

}


#topBottomBar.top-animation{
    -webkit-transition: top 2s ease;
    transition: top 2s ease;
    top: 0px;
}
#topBottomBar.bottom-animation{
    -webkit-transition: bottom 2s ease;
    transition: bottom 2s ease;
    bottom: 0px;
}



#topBottomBar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box!important;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-clip: padding-box!important;
    line-height: 1.2;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    float: none;
    z-index: 2147483635;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    filter: none;
}


#topBottomBar  #buttonlink
{
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
 line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    max-width: 317px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #ffffff!important;
    background: #ffcd53!important;
    font-family: inherit;
}

#topBottomBar .fa{

    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-size: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    color: #d3d3d3!important;
    text-indent: 0!important;
    top: 0!important;
    left: 0!important;
    padding: 10px;
    background: 0 0!important;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    display: block!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;

    opacity: .5!important;
}

#topBottomBar  .fa:hover
{
 
 animation: colorChange 2s;
}

@keyframes colorChange{
 from {color: #c2c2c2;}
 to {color: #FFFFFF;}
}



#topBottomBar #closelink
{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: transform 200ms,opacity 200ms!important;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
    transition-duration: 200ms, 200ms;
    transition-timing-function: initial, initial;
    transition-delay: initial, initial;
}


#topBottomBar #closelink:hover{

 animation: colorChange 1s;
/* Safari */
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

 /* Firefox */
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

 /* IE */
 -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

 /* Opera */
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

#topBottomBar .top-fixed
{
 top:-42px !important;

}

.bottom-fixed
{
 bottom: -42px!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bar effectschange</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <a href="#">Get new version</a>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac blandit lectus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean metus lorem, tincidunt eu enim et, rutrum vehicula sem. Vivamus scelerisque viverra nisl vitae condimentum. Proin ultricies aliquet molestie. Proin faucibus quam in felis egestas malesuada. Fusce convallis leo sem, sed laoreet est eleifend at. Nullam rutrum massa lacus, vel viverra odio consequat eu. Curabitur pharetra ligula auctor pretium placerat. Nulla non arcu porta, placerat lacus vel, pretium tellus. Phasellus tempor, massa quis condimentum bibendum, erat mi rhoncus mauris, sit amet fringilla elit leo id erat. Sed vehicula tellus quis turpis mollis auctor. Praesent quis tempor lectus. Nullam ut tincidunt odio, vitae varius magna.</p>
      <p>Duis vel placerat magna. Morbi ac cursus tortor. Pellentesque consequat, turpis ut mollis dictum, arcu diam sodales nisi, at hendrerit nunc velit vel metus. Mauris luctus sed dolor ac feugiat. In luctus erat vel fringilla rhoncus. Nulla id orci maximus, hendrerit nisl varius, hendrerit massa. Maecenas velit mauris, dictum malesuada massa id, varius lobortis orci. Vivamus quis placerat lorem. Suspendisse pellentesque mattis nunc sed semper. Proin et magna suscipit, aliquam ligula et, placerat est. Etiam tempor augue orci, et aliquet erat ultricies efficitur. Vivamus vitae fermentum tortor, nec porttitor ligula. Integer vel dapibus nunc. Vestibulum quis eros pretium, euismod velit id, dapibus sem.</p>

      <button id="up">Up</button>
      <i class="fa fa-btc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <button id="down">Down</button>

      <p>Aenean lorem enim, condimentum quis augue ultrices, molestie volutpat nibh. Praesent metus mi, dapibus in commodo non, mattis nec dolor. Phasellus a urna sem. Pellentesque sem justo, semper sed iaculis sed, mollis ac risus. Fusce et consectetur nisl, nec fringilla sem. Sed egestas lorem eros, a accumsan sem commodo vitae. Nulla porta, turpis id eleifend facilisis, nibh tellus feugiat diam, sit amet convallis leo diam in sem. Praesent venenatis vitae ante at bibendum. Morbi in mauris quam. Nam quis eros ullamcorper, porttitor elit vitae, hendrerit neque.</p>
      <p>Vivamus a bibendum neque. Pellentesque vestibulum id magna at ornare. Sed volutpat molestie dolor, vitae congue ipsum pellentesque at. Duis ornare nunc in lorem ullamcorper rhoncus. Maecenas dictum purus massa, et pulvinar erat maximus ac. Pellentesque in diam consequat, vehicula orci porta, condimentum leo. Morbi ut dui sed massa accumsan commodo. Sed nibh eros, iaculis quis tellus ut, ultricies placerat nisi. Curabitur eu rhoncus ex. Sed interdum tristique purus nec commodo.</p>
      <p><p>
        
      </p>Suspendisse vulputate mauris et turpis venenatis congue. Nullam eu rutrum odio, sed aliquet nibh. Aliquam porttitor ultrices laoreet. Pellentesque pulvinar molestie malesuada. Sed pretium vestibulum dolor, scelerisque posuere velit tincidunt non. Sed blandit eleifend dapibus. Ut erat tortor, cursus non consequat pharetra, suscipit eu felis. Proin sit amet massa massa. Sed urna erat, molestie a ante ac, imperdiet cursus nunc. Proin iaculis eros quis diam tincidunt, porttitor convallis nunc luctus. Phasellus vestibulum, sem sit amet sodales ultricies, lorem tortor tempor nisl, non lacinia eros augue sed ex.</p>


  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>Join us in development! </p>
  </div>

<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to animate a bar made dynamically in javascript, by using a CSS transition. The animation doesn't work. First I create my bar with javascript, and show it based on a `click` event.

I read that transition with jaascript is added as extra class to existing element. Is it possible that when I make element with javascript and also add the `id` and `class` with javascript, the transition happens faster than the original style and it doesn't appear to run at all?

```
TopBottomBar.prototype.show = function(){ 
  var allNodes = document.body.childNodes;
  console.log(!document.getElementById('topBottomBar'));

  if(this.position === 'top' && !document.getElementById('topBottomBar')) {
    document.body.insertBefore(this.baseDiv, allNodes[0]);
    this.baseDiv.className = ' top-animation';
    document.getElementById('closelink').addEventListener('click',this.hide.bind(this));
  } else if(this.position === 'bottom' && !document.getElementById('topBottomBar')) {
    document.body.insertBefore(this.baseDiv, allNodes[allNodes.length - 1].nextSibling);
    this.baseDiv.className = 'bottom-animation';
    document.getElementById('closelink').addEventListener('click', this.hide.bind(this));
  } else {
    console.log('Ziomus bar istnieje, tymczasowa wiadomość');
    return;
  }
}

TopBottomBar.prototype.createNewBar = function(){
  var baseDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var button = document.createElement("a");
  button.href = this.link;  
  var icon = document.createElement("i");
  icon.className += 'fa fa-btc';
  button.id += 'buttonlink';
  var textButton = document.createTextNode(this.message);
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  var closeButton = document.createTextNode("X");
  span.id += 'closelink';

  span.appendChild(closeButton);
  button.appendChild(textButton);
  baseDiv.appendChild(icon);
  baseDiv.appendChild(button);
  baseDiv.appendChild(span);
  baseDiv.id += 'topBottomBar';

  if (this.position === 'top') {
   baseDiv.className += 'top-fixed';
  }

  if(this.position ===  'bottom') {
    baseDiv.className += 'bottom-fixed';
  }

  return baseDiv;
}
```

top-animation and bottom-animation are my css transitions

```
#topBottomBar.top-animation {
  -webkit-transition: top 2s ease;
  transition: top 2s ease;
  top: 0px;
}
```

The starting point for the `top` property is -42px, which is the height of my bar. I tested it on an easy example with one `div` hardcoded in HTML and everything was fine. The `div` went from -42px top to 0.

## EDITED, added whole code, what i want to achieve is to make this bar animated with transition. There are 2 buttons which show bar.

Comment: I recommend you add a fiddle or snippet to your question.

Comment: Can you add some markup to your question? Thanks.

Comment: Problem solved. When i want to trigger transition on element in which i dynamically add css style, the styles need to be added with delay between them. So using setTimeout when adding 2nd style was the answer.